# Weird: can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I don't understand why my query runs fine in phpMyAdmin and in my php script it gives me the message: **can't specify target table for update in FROM clause**!!!

```
update tableA set 
Field1 = round(round((select (select br.FieldA from tableB br where tableA.id=br.id and tableA.id2=br.id2) as x),4) - round(tableA.FieldA,4),4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. You cannot select in the nested query the same table you're updating now.

The better solution will be to use joins in your update. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Comment: @zerkms: I agree with you that by definition shouldn't work, but why it is not true in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @Parkyprg: why are you trying to defend "wrong" query, that should not work, instead of rewriting it in a proper way with joins?

Comment: Just to be clear, this form of UPDATE is perfectly valid in standard SQL so it isn't so surprising that Parkyprg wanted to write it that way. It's purely a limitation of MySQL that doesn't permit it.

Comment: For both of you - thank you for your responses. However I have posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844228/help-me-with-this-update-in-mysql - you will see what I wanted to do.

Comment: did you noticed that I replied to your answer with a working query at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843217/weird-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/4843262#4843262 ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work with multi-table update:

```
UPDATE tableA, tableB
SET tableA.Field1 = round(round(tableB.FieldA, 4) - round(tableA.FieldA,4), 4)
WHERE tableA.id=tableB.id AND tableA.id2=tableB.id2;
```

Search for `join` in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: I noticed your query, that's why I upvoted your reply. But I am affraid that my update is more complex than this. Check here to see my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844228/help-me-with-this-update-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using multiple copies of the same table like this:

```
UPDATE tablename, tablename b 
SET tablename.col1 = val 
WHERE tablename.col1 = b.col1 AND b.col2 IN (val1,val2,val3);
```

The `val` in the above query can also be a variable like `b.col2`.